# htaccess redirect all posts one page from php to html

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

my site setup with htaccess not directing from php to html you can acsess to both links
as below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)_([a-zA-Z0-9]{9}).html$ watch.php?vid=$2
```

example with links

```
https://www.example.com/watch.php?vid=1c0bfb407
```

and

```
https://www.example.com/post-name_1c0bfb407.html
```

I want it to force only be accessed through :

```
https://www.example.com/post-name_1c0bfb407.html
```

Comment: The rule seems to be setup upside down. From html to php.

Comment: why don't you just save the files which are php as .php?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} watch\.php\?vid=(.+)\sHTTP.*$ 
RewriteRule ^        post-name_%1.html?  [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)_([a-zA-Z0-9]{9}).html$  watch.php?vid=$2 [L]
```

**Note:** considering post-name fixed.

Comment: thanks but post-name is example what about other (25K) posts ?

Comment: @saykoo so , you should make another param to be reference like  watch,php?postname=$1&vid=$2 , you get it?

Comment: but i dont have ideas with htaccess and php

Comment: @saykoo sorry but you should follow my first suggestion , unless there is another param server could not be able to figure out a post name

Comment: This link https://www.example.com/watch.php?vid=1c0bfb407
 should look like  https://www.example.com/watch.php?postname=$1&vid=1c0bfb407
or https://www.example.com/watch.php?vid=post-name_1c0bfb407